# Unable to get WCFExtras to work with WCF Service

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I am getting an error that I can't pull down the metadata for the service.  When I look at the WCFExtras Sample, it all looks good and the sample works fine.  The only difference is that my WCF Service is .NET 4.0.

This is what my web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

    <customErrors mode="Off" />

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CDITecServices.TECServiceHelperBehavior"
               name="CDITecServices.ITECServiceHelper">
        <endpoint address=""
          behaviorConfiguration="CDITecServices.TECServiceHelperEndpointBehavior"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CDITecServices.ITECServiceHelper"/>
      </service>
    </services>


    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CDITecServices.TECServiceHelperEndpointBehavior">
          <wsdlExtensions singleFile="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CDITecServices.TECServiceHelperBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"
                        httpHelpPageEnabled="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <!-- Declare that we have an extension called WSDL Extras-->
        <add name="wsdlExtensions"
             type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtras, Version=1.0.0.0,
                   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/> 
  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

This is what my interface looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using WCFExtras.Wsdl.Documentation;

namespace CDITecServices
{
    [XmlComments]
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITECServiceHelper
    {

        [OperationContract]
        void DownloadDataFile(string OrderTicketId, string Username,
                              string Password, string UserDatabase);

        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetRecordsFromFile(string OrderTicketId, ref long StartIndex);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
}
```

Comment: "can't pull down the MetaData" - how are you "pulling" it? And what is the exact error?

Comment: trying to either run the svc in Visual Studio or trying to create a reference to the service from Visual Studio.  If I deploy the svc and then try to browse it, I get the message "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled."

Answer (score 2):

Update your service name from `CDITecServices.ITECServiceHelper` to the class name `CDITecServices.TECServiceHelper`

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="CDITecServices.TECServiceHelperBehavior" name="CDITecServices.TECServiceHelper">
```

The name attribute on the <service> tag must match the name of your service class, fully qualified including namespace.